# Why isn't vb.net codebehind recognising my asp control id?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have copy and pasted some VB.NET and some ASP.NET into existing files in my solution from another to fix a common problem. However, the VB isn't recognising the ID of the asp:Panel controls that I've brought over. Any ideas why this might be and how to solve it?

```
<asp:Panel ID="passwordPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="SaveNewPWD">

passwordPanel.Visible = False
```

Comment: Have you checked the `passwordPanel` variable exists in the designer file?

Comment: You need to show complete code.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. The code I had copied included the <@ Page %> tag, which contained different capitalisation of inheritance compared to where I had copied it from. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting actual compiler errors when you try to open the page or are you just seeing red underlining in Visual Studio (assuming that you're using Visual Studio)

If you're just seeing the error flagged up in Visual Studio, try closing your page and opening it again - I sometimes have to do this with Visual Studio 2005 to get it to recognise newly added controls.

Also, are you sure that your Panel is a top-level element?  It's not nested in a repeater or similar, is it? :)